# Issue with Service Workers when switching from CRA to Next JS

Tags: next.js, create-react-app, service-worker

So we recently changed our landing page from create-react-app to using Next.js. Our old create-react-app had a basic default service worker registered on users browsers.

Whenever I switched over to our new Next.js website, we realized that users who had been there before would continue to get a crappy cached version of the old website.

I've found a couple of discussions talking about this issue already, but neither solutions seem to be working for me. Those two discussions are:

- [A website is not refreshing because of caching of service worker, after switching from React to Next.js. How to force update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65762531/a-website-is-not-refreshing-because-of-caching-of-service-worker-after-switchin?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
- https://www.asapdevelopers.com/service-worker-issue-nextjs-framework/

Both of these solutions essentially consist of adding a new service worker file to your Next project with some code to delete the existing service workers. That code looks like

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then((registrations) => {
      console.log("--");
      for (let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister().then((bool) => {
          console.log("unregister: ", bool);
        });
      }
      if (registrations.length) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

So i've tried this. My old service worker was served via a file at route `OUR_URL/service-worker.js`. I added a public directory to my Next project and added a file with the same name and the code above to my project. I then linked this file in my `_document.js` and can confirm that it runs, as well as I'm able to find it on my Next.js site. The URL for both the new and old files are identical. Unfortunately though, it looks like the issue persists.

In one of the other articles linked above, it also mentions putting this file in the root directory of your Next project. This doesn't make much sense to me as it isn't then being served in anyway that I'm aware of, but I gave this a shot as well, still with no luck.

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here, or what I could do to fix this? Essentially we just want to force remove any and all old service worker so that our new website loads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Service workers are (at least generally) registered via the site itself and not automatically found by browsers (at least not yet).

This code (unregistering all service workers for the domain) should go in whatever is being sent from next.js to the browser (e.g. index.js). If you put this on your home page all users going there should have the problem resolved. If you have reason to suspect (based on traffic data) that users have other pages bookmarked you might want to include this in a universal bundle or footer.